# Understanding Pullback of Cartier Divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, pullback

Let $g\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $D=(U_i,f_i)$ be a Cartier Divisor on $Y$. I've seen the following definition of the pullback of $D$: $g^*D\colon=(g^{-1}(U_i),f_i\circ g)$, as long as $g(X)\not\subseteq \operatorname{supp} D$.
The problem is that I don't understand what the composition $f_i\circ g$ should mean. For any open $U\subseteq Y$, there is a bijection between $O_Y(U)$ and the functions $U\to \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1$, so I guess the idea is to identify each $f_i$ as a quotient of two functions like that for some open $U$, compose and then go back through the same identification in $X$.

However, this procedure requires a lot of identification, and I wonder if there is a better characterization of the pullback of Cartier divisors. I've looked in some books but all I can find is the pullback of Weil Divisors. Also, by the characterization I found, I don't think it is clear why we should put the hypothesis $g(X)\not\subseteq \operatorname{supp} D$ to define the pullback.

Could you please give me a light on this, maybe also with some concrete examples of calculating pullbacks of Cartier divisors, so I could understand this a little better?

Comment: It's not clear what is confusing you. You have an open cover of $Y$ and functions on on those opens such that if $y \in U_i \cap U_j$, then $f_i(y) = 0$ if and only if $f_j(y)$. By taking inverse images, you get an open cover of $X$, and the vanishing condition on the $f_i$ is preserved by composing (morally, $(f_i\circ g)(x) = 0$ iff $f_i(y) = 0$ iff $f_j(y) = 0$ iff $(f_j \circ g)(x) = 0$, for each $x \in X$ satisfying $g(x) = y$). The support condition is because if $g(X) \subseteq \operatorname{supp} D$ then $f_i \circ g$ is identically $0$ for all $i$...

Comment: ... In other words, we want $g(X) \cap \operatorname{supp} D$ to have codimension $1$ as a subscheme of $g(X)$.

Comment: I agree that this is confusing, since the map of structure sheaves for a morphism of LRS's $g$ is not in general given by $\varphi \mapsto \varphi \circ g$, since as you said this doesn't really make sense. I would instead write this as $(U, \varphi_U) \mapsto (g^{-1}(U), g^\#(\varphi_U))$ where $g^\#$ is the associated map on ring sheaves.